# Why is 'Protocols' followed by 'works' and not 'work' in 'The exact scheme used by Internet Protocols works as follows'?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> The exact scheme used by Internet Protocols works as follows.

Protocols is plural, so shouldn't it be followed by work?

Comment: The subject of *works* is not *protocols*, but *scheme*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said, the subject is *scheme*, that's why it takes the third person form of the present simple.

In this case we have shortened relative clause (non-defining or non-restrictive), so we can better look at the subject:

> The exact scheme, **which is used** by Internet Protocols, works as follows.

Remove the commas and the subject is clearly identified:

> The exact scheme *works* as follows.